# kinetic.js load stage...lost references

Tags: kineticjs

I have a problem in understanding how the 
Kinetic.Node.create(myJson, 'container') 
function works.

I have a simple project. Generate a circleLayer and add a circle. Now I can remove the circle by     circleLayer.removeChildren();
But when I save the stage to JSON and reload it the reference to the circle got los...now I can not delete it anymore...
Here is my code.

Has anybody an idea?

```
var myJson;
var stage;
var circleLayer;
var myWidth = 500;
var myHeigth = 350;

function createStagesAndLayer() {

    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: myWidth,
        height: myHeigth
    });

    circleLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(circleLayer);
}
function deleteCircle() {
    circleLayer.removeChildren();
    circleLayer.draw();
}
function saveData() {
    myJson = null;
    myJson = stage.toJSON();
}function loadData() {
    if (myJson == null) {
        alert("Keine Daten gefunden!!");
        return;
    }


   // I need to remoce it...otherwise my drawing area will grow. But I think here somewhere is the problem
    stage.remove(circleLayer);
    stage = Kinetic.Node.create(myJson, 'container');
}
function generateCircle() {
   var  circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        radius: 30,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        draggable: true
    });
    circleLayer.add(circle);
    circleLayer.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From KineticJS [documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#.create):

> Kinetic.Node.create(JSON, container) create node with JSON
>   string. De-serializtion does not generate custom shape drawing
>   functions, images, or event handlers (this would make the serialized
>   object huge). If your app uses custom shapes, images, and event
>   handlers (it probably does), then you need to select the appropriate
>   shapes after loading the stage and set these properties via on(),
>   setDrawFunc(), and setImage() methods

So I believe, the variable the local variable assignment also won't work and hence your problem. I'm working on a similar project and your question gives me another thing to worry about :( but +1 for a heads up :)

Comment: this answer has given me a bit light from point of view how is this create fromjson work. It give my undo/redo approach over its head :) . I have to find another way then.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you call your function saveData().
If you first delete circleLayer and than save your Stage, surely your circle got lost.

If you will not loose the reference to the circle, try to hide it, instead of deleting.

circle.hide();

if you have more than one circles generated you can hide all by using id or name in circle creation.

example:

```
function generateCircle() {
var  circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    draggable: true,
    name: circle
});
circleLayer.add(circle);
circleLayer.draw();
}

var Circle_hide = circleLayer.get('.circle');

if (Circle_hide[0].attrs.visible == true){
    for (var i=0; i < Circle_hide.length; i++){
   Circle_hide[i].hide();
}
}
else {
for (var i=0; i < Circle_hide.length; i++){
   Circle_hide[i].show();
}
}
circleLayer.draw();
```

you can add a button click event for hiding or showing the circles, can save the data to JSON and circles will still be saved in your JSON file.